# How do i set TextView value to sum to recyclerview item values outside recyclerview adapter

Tags: android

I want to set Total to sum of the green values below `Textview` in the recyclerview. Here is a screenshot of my app fragment.

[image]
this is my adapter class

```js
class InvoiceAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<InvoiceAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

    Context mcontext;
    List<ProductVariables> productlist;
    ProductVariables variables;
    List<Double> mytota = new ArrayList<>();


    public InvoiceAdapter(Context mcontext, List<ProductVariables> productlist) {
        this.mcontext = mcontext;
        this.productlist = productlist;
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView producttransfered;
        TextView rateofselectedproduct;
        EditText enterqty;
        TextView totalitemamt;
        TextView subTotal;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            producttransfered = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.producttransfered);
            rateofselectedproduct = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rateofselectedproduct);
            totalitemamt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.totalitemamt);
            subTotal = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subTotal);
            enterqty = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.enterqty);


        }
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View invoiceview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custominvoicedetail, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(invoiceview);
        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        variables = productlist.get(position);

        TextView transfereditemname = holder.producttransfered;
        transfereditemname.setText(variables.getProductname());

        TextView rates = holder.rateofselectedproduct;
        rates.setText(Double.toString(variables.getRate()));



        holder.enterqty.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                String qty = s.toString();

                try {
                    double input = Double.parseDouble(qty);
                    Double rate = Double.parseDouble(holder.rateofselectedproduct.getText().toString());
                    Double total = rate * input;

                    holder.totalitemamt.setText(Double.toString(total));


                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    holder.totalitemamt.setText("");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    holder.totalitemamt.setText("");
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });





    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return productlist.size();
    }




}
```

this is my fragment class

public class InvoiceDetailFragment extends Fragment {

```
RecyclerView invoicedproducts;
Button showTransfered;
InvoiceAdapter invoiceAdapter;
TextView subTotal;
List<ProductVariables> mytotal;
ProductVariables calculatetotal;


public InvoiceDetailFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_invoice_detail, container, false);


    subTotal = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.subTotal);
    showTransfered = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.showTransfered);
    invoicedproducts = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.invoicedproducts);

    showTransfered.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            GetTotal(v);
        }
    });


    return view;
}

public void GetTotal(View view) {


}







public void SetMessage(List<ProductVariables> productlists){
    List<List<ProductVariables>> ite2 = new ArrayList<>();
    ite2.add(productlists);
    invoicedproducts.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    InvoiceAdapter adapter = new InvoiceAdapter(getContext(), productlists);
    invoicedproducts.setAdapter(adapter);
```

strong text
    }

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Two ways you can do this-

1. You can make a interface to update the value of total outside your recyclerview adapter.
2. Make a method in your fragment class which takes integer value in parameter and set total.Pass you Fragment object in Adapter constructor. 
   Using that fragment object call that method which you have created in fragment and pass your value.

I hope it helps you.

```
        public class InvoiceAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    Context mcontext;
        List<ProductVariables> productlist;
        ProductVariables variables;
        List<Double> mytota = new ArrayList<>();
      private SubTotalListener subTotalListener;


        public InvoiceAdapter(Context mcontext, List<ProductVariables> productlist, SubTotalListener subTotalListener) {
    this.subTotalListener = subTotalListener;
            this.mcontext = mcontext;
            this.productlist = productlist;
        }

        public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

            TextView producttransfered;
            TextView rateofselectedproduct;
            EditText enterqty;
            TextView totalitemamt;
            TextView subTotal;

            public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                producttransfered = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.producttransfered);
                rateofselectedproduct = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rateofselectedproduct);
                totalitemamt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.totalitemamt);
                subTotal = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subTotal);
                enterqty = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.enterqty);


            }
        }

        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            Context context = parent.getContext();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View invoiceview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custominvoicedetail, parent, false);
            MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(invoiceview);
            return myViewHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            variables = productlist.get(position);

            TextView transfereditemname = holder.producttransfered;
            transfereditemname.setText(variables.getProductname());

            TextView rates = holder.rateofselectedproduct;
            rates.setText(Double.toString(variables.getRate()));



            holder.enterqty.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    String qty = s.toString();

                    try {
                        double input = Double.parseDouble(qty);
                        Double rate = Double.parseDouble(holder.rateofselectedproduct.getText().toString());
                        Double total = rate * input;

                        holder.totalitemamt.setText(Double.toString(total));


                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        holder.totalitemamt.setText("");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        holder.totalitemamt.setText("");
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });
        }

public void countTotal(){
// Calculate your total amount here from your arraylist and pass in below call.
subTotalListener.onSubTotalUpdate(total);
}


        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return productlist.size();
        }

    public interface SubTotalListener {
                    void onSubTotalUpdate(int total);
        }
```

In Your Fragment Class, Do as below-

```
public class InvoiceDetailFragment extends Fragment implements InvoiceAdapter.SubTotalListener {

RecyclerView invoicedproducts;
Button showTransfered;
InvoiceAdapter invoiceAdapter;
TextView subTotal;
List<ProductVariables> mytotal;
ProductVariables calculatetotal;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_invoice_detail, container, false);


    subTotal = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.subTotal);
    showTransfered = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.showTransfered);
    invoicedproducts = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.invoicedproducts);

invoiceAdapter = new InvoiceAdapter(this,mytotal,this);
    return view;
}

@Override
void onSubTotalUpdate(int total){
subTotal.setText(""+total);
}
```

Comment: when i create a method in my adapter and call that method in my fragment i get a nullpointer

Comment: i have uploaded my full code without any interface or methods..the green values in textview are generated via edittext watcher..but now i also need to generate the total value outside that adapter in the textview showing total in the fragment. like you suggested, i created a method returning ,y arraylist but got a nullpointer error

Comment: I have edited my post, Please have a look in my code. Hope It helps you.

Comment: Thanks for this, i have implemented the interface, but i cant seem to understand your code fully. initializing "CartListItemAdapter" in fragment and Elegantbutton onvaluechange, please can you reference my code so i understand better?

Comment: Check it now. And I had made an method countTotal() in this method you have to sum all amounts from list.